# Fitting URL item in articles' bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, fit

I encountered a problem with fitting an URL in my bibliography. Adding a space is unsuitable because the URL is no more valid. Do you have any advice? I used the following codes:

```
\vspace{2mm}    

\begin{hangparas}{1cm}{1}
Sun, L. \& Widdicks, M. (2016). Why do employees like to be paid with Options?: A multi-period prospect theory approach. \textit{Journal Of Corporate Finance, 38}, 106-125. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2016.03.002
\end{hangparas}

\vspace{2mm}
```

[image]

Comment: either `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\url{..}`

Comment: If this does not help, please add a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

With the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package you will be able to click on the url and inmediatly it will redirect you to the website. Although the line ends while typing your url, this will not affect the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{hanging} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{1cm}{1} 
Sun, L. \& Widdicks, M. (2016). Why do employees like to be paid with Options?: A multi-period prospect theory approach. \textit{Journal Of Corporate Finance, 38}, 106-125. \url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcorpfin.2016.03.002} 
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]