# Remove redundant space in references

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite several websites and am having an issue due to the unwanted space between the words in the title. I created following the minimal example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2\topmargin}

\begin{document}
\cite{cg}
\cite{deltaairlines}
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image: In the image]

You can see that there are big gaps between the words in the first citation.

If I remove `\usepackage{hyperref}`, the problem seems like solved, however, it is an important package to fit the link into the page. So when I remove it in the original file, it messes up bunch of other citations.

If I remove `\usepackage{times}`, it once again solves the problem. Yet, this time it increases the total number of pages since I use that package to arrange my tables.

I do not know how I can solve this problem while still using the same packages. Is there any other package that I can use? or Does anyone have an alternative way to solve this issue?

I am also sharing the two entries in the bib file. Note that I removed the `note` part to create the MWE.

```
@misc{cg,
author = {},
title = {{This is the website that I would like to cite }},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.myWebsite.org/?abstract&did=802138}}
}
@misc{deltaairlines,
author = {},
title = {{Delta Airlines}},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.deltaaair.com/content/travel-info/our-aircraft/}}
}
```

Comment: Are the urls in a `\url{}`? [Maybe this helps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335357/172164). Otherwise please include the items in you bibliography [like this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/172164), then it's easier to tell what is going on.

Comment: Try replacing `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}`.

Comment: @TivV I added the entries in the bib file into my post.

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @ball_jan - Did you run a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more after making the suggested change?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I did. I removed ```\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}```, and added ```\usepackage{xurl}```. It gives me an error.

Comment: @ball_jan - Please see the answer I just posted: I do *not* get error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions, in decreasing order of importance:

- Replace `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}`.
- Load the `xurl` and `hyperref` packages *last*.
- Instead of loading the `times` package, load the `newtxtext` package. The `times` package makes `courier` the default monospaced font. Courier is not exactly a "condensed" monospaced font. In fact, it's quite the opposite. Not great for long URL strings, for sure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{cg,
author = {},
title = {{This is the website that I would like to cite}},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.myWebsite.org/?abstract&did=802138}},
month = jul,
year = {2016},
note = {(Accessed on 12/29/2019)}
}
@misc{deltaairlines,
author = {},
title = {{Delta Airlines}},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.deltaaair.com/content/travel-info/our-aircraft/}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 12/04/2019)}
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

%%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2\topmargin}

%% Load 'xurl' and 'hyperref' last:
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{cg}
\cite{deltaairlines}
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Only replacing the ```times``` package with the ```newtxtext``` solved my issue. It caused to have another extra page in the original document tho.